# $interval.cancel not destroy timer in http.get

Tags: angularjs

I need to call $http request every 30s so I set a timer, but on route change, the timer is still working in the background

```
$scope.timer = function(){
        $interval(function () {
        $scope.refreshData();
    }, 30000);
}
$http.get(serviceBase + 'users/test')
            .then(function (res) {
                $scope.dataForEdit = res.data;
                angular.forEach($scope.dataForEdit.campaign_items, function(value, key){
                if(value.bench_downloaded == false || value.bench_notified == false){
                    $scope.timer();
                }
            })
```

And on state change I want to destroy interval, I tried with this in the same controller, I get alert, but the interval is still working

```
$scope.$on('$destroy',function(){
                alert('try');
                $interval.cancel($scope.timer);
              });
```

Here is a working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/jhednn9UTve11yMf2SFa?p=preview). Try to change state and watch in console. The interval is still working.
What am I doing wrong? Thnx

Comment: You are not passing promise to `$interval.cancel()`. You are passing `timer` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$interval return value is used to cancel the interval. You need to retain the interval return value and use that to do $interval.cancel(theReturnValue);

Here is a working plunk. When I  change to route2, the interval is canceled due to $destroy and starts back again when goto route1. You can also call the destroyInterval() at any time to cancel .

https://next.plnkr.co/edit/WjHzG08rWAoLfeSP

adding more notes..

the $scope.stop is no longer needed. You should destroyInterval() as well if the http request fails so add a .catch or an error callback. Key is to handle all scenarios that may make that interval go in error state.

Comment: This is true answer, thnx.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you mean this: (added return statement, so $scope.timer becomes interval)

```
$scope.timer = function(){
        return $interval(function () {
        $scope.refreshData();
    }, 30000);
}
```

Comment: i try this, but still the same. Interval is not destroyed

Comment: Also I think he needs to cancel the `$http.get` request on `$destroy`. If he changes the route with the request running, when the request finishes he is going to trigger the timer once again.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to pass promise to `$interval.cancel()`. Try below code,

```
$scope.stop = '';
$scope.timer = function(){
     $scope.stop = $interval(function () { // promise
     $scope.refreshData(); 
  }, 30000);
}

$scope.$on('$destroy',function(){
   alert('try');
   $interval.cancel($scope.stop);
});
```

check the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/bNyOxsZEpv8FVg2JhI3a?p=preview)

Comment: @Arter I had made the silly mistake. Taking promise from the wrong function. I have edited my code. `$interval` returns promise.

Comment: Thnx, this is also a nice solution, but with this, in my code intervals duplicate http.get, and on state change, they destroy only one call. Another still making call to API.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176302/discussion-between-arter-and-kaustubh-khare).